# Prevent caching javascript file, Spring

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, cache-control

I have my project structured this way :

```
   src/main/java
        com.test.project
        com.test.project.configuration
        com.test.project.controller
        com.test.project.model
        com.test.project.repository
        com.test.project.service
   src/main/resources
       static
           css
           js
             jquery..
             calculate.js
           images
       templates
          admin
          user
             statistics.html
          login.html
```

In my calculate.js file I have an ajax call to the database, and there's some values I retrieve to show in a table in the statistics.html
  But the thing is, once calculated those values get cached and when I call the calculate.js again for other data, the same retrieve info from the first time show again.

I tried adding this on the application.properties

```
spring.resources.chain.cache=false
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/**
```

But they're still there.
How do I fix this ?

Edit:

this is my rest controller :
          @RequestMapping(value = "calculatedResults/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public SurveyComparison getComparisonResultById(@PathVariable("id") long id, final HttpServletResponse response){
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        return calculateService.getSurveyById(id);
    }

my ajax call :

```
function getSurveyResults(id){
var url="/calculatedResults/"+id;
requestZ=$.getJSON(url,function(data){
    surveyResults=data;
});
}

getSurveyResults(surveyId);

$.when(requestZ).then(function(){

document.getElementById("score1").innerHTML=surveyResults.scored1;}
```

And I fill out some columns of certain id with different values

Comment: judging from your question, this is not an issue about the browser downloading an outdated version of `calculate.js`, but the browser fetching outdated data from the server using AJAX. Could you provide more information about what your code actually does, and how it should behave?

Comment: I edited the code and added that part in. Basically, I make an ajax call to get some data.
And then on I pull out data and put it in a certain element with a given id

Answer (score 0):

Try this to stop caching of page as it works for me:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
```